# how to bind click event to a particular id of a div in a loop in angular2

Tags: angular

How to change text of id="itemid0" when id="buttonitemid0" is clicked?

```
app.component.ts
-----------------
   bb = 'cat';
changeText(index){

}
     app.component.html
    -----------------------------

        <div class="col-xs-2" *ngFor="let item of items;let k=index;">
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="itemid{{index}}">aa</div>
        <button type="button" id="buttonitemid{{index}}" (click)="changeText(index)">btnn</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the index in a field in the component and then bind to this field

### app.component.ts

```
clickedIdx :number;
changeText(index){
  this.clickedIdx = index;
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<div class="col-xs-2" *ngFor="let item of itmes"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" *ngFor="let item of items;let k=index;">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="itemid{{index}}">aa</div>
    <button type="button" id="buttonitemid{{clickedIdx}}" (click)="changeText(k)">btnn</button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you help this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855627/how-to-show-hide-dynamic-id-of-divs-in-angular2/46856004?noredirect=1#comment80661323_46856004

Comment: How to pass some other data to id="itemid0" eg;- bb  when we click buttonitemid0.

Comment: I dont see any change in the question and your answer, as text is not changed id-itemid0 when corresponding buttonitemid0 is clicked.

Comment: Can you, please tell me how  method changeText(index){
  this.clickedIdx = index;
} is changing text 'aa' to  text 'bb' when corresponding button is clicked? Sorry, but its not working.

Comment: Where should `aa` or `bb` come from? Seems to be arbitrary. Honestly, I have no idea what the question is about.

Comment: <div class="col-xs-12" id="itemid{{index}}">aa</div>