# How to toggle two divs when clicked while in a loop in angular4

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

It is a reference to the question asked [how to show/hide dynamic id of div's in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855627/how-to-show-hide-dynamic-id-of-divs-in-angular2/46856004?noredirect=1#comment80661323_46856004).

I have prepared a plunker which will display the problem which i am facing?
here, I want to toggle btn1 and btn2 separately in the 4 boxes.
The requirement is when in box1, the btn1 is clicked , `'subRegion'` should show & `'productLine'` should hide; when btn2 is clicked,`'productLine'` should show and `'subRegion'` should hide. Similarly, among box2,box3,box4.
Here, clicking btn2 from box1(one among 4 boxes)is displaying the content in every boxes. How to fix that?

Here is plunker link, https://plnkr.co/edit/E3ykbvXIPtQwVqe9cnQA?p=preview

code:-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
 <div class="col-xs-3 rmpm" *ngFor="let kpi of kpiName;let index=index;">
 <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm" style="height:80px;border:1px solid;width:70px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">A</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm" style="border:1px solid;width:70px;margin-top:10px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">

  <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm" style="border:1px solid;padding:0px;margin:0px;">

   <!--btn 1 should be by default active and have blue color -->

  <div class="col-xs-6 rmpm" id="btn1{{index}}"  (click)="showsubid(index,'btn1')" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border-right:1px solid;">btn1</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 rmpm" id="btn2{{index}}" (click)="showproid(index,'btn2')"  style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">btn2</div>
  </div>

 <!--By default will be displayed when btn1 is active,this will show when btn1 is clicked and hide when btn2 is clicked -->

  <div class="col-xs-12" id="subid{{index}}" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" >
     <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm filteredDataRow" *ngFor="let subDta of subRegion;let k = index;" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
     <div class=" col-xs-12 rmpm filteredDataName " (click)='loadSubRegionData()' style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border-top:1px solid">{{subRegion[k]}}</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <!--this will show when btn2 is clicked and hide when btn1 is clicked -->

    <div class="col-xs-12"  id="proid{{index}}"   style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" *ngIf="pro == 0" >
     <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm filteredDataRow"  *ngFor="let subDta of productLine;let k = index;" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" >
     <div class=" col-xs-12 rmpm filteredDataName " (click)='loadSubRegionData()' style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border-top:1px solid">{{productLine[k]}}</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
    kpiName = ['s', 'TO ','d','e'];
  subRegion = ['Ch', 'Ia', 'Ja', 'Ke', 'SE'];
   productLine = ['6A', '7T', '9T', 'UV', 'BA'];
pro: any;
  constructor() {

  }

showsubid(index,btnid){
  alert(index)
   alert(btnid+index)
}
showproid(index){
   alert(index)
    // alert(id+index)
    this.pro = index;
}
}
```

Comment: As for best practice, if you have more than 5 lines in your component template, use a separate html file.  In that way, your component will look cleaner and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your request. On clicking the button the specific content of that section should be displayed. I have updated the code: https://plnkr.co/edit/TEbI45K2TZkRYd84jYft?p=preview

```
    //our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
 <div class="col-xs-3 rmpm" *ngFor="let kpi of kpiName;let index=index;">
 <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm" style="height:80px;border:1px solid;width:70px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">A</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm" style="border:1px solid;width:70px;margin-top:10px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">

  <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm" style="border:1px solid;padding:0px;margin:0px;">

   <!--btn 1 should be by default active and have blue color -->

  <div class="col-xs-6 rmpm" id="btn1{{index}}"  (click)="showsubid(index,'btn1')" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border-right:1px solid;">btn1</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 rmpm" id="btn2{{index}}" (click)="showproid(index,'btn2')"  style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">btn2</div>
  </div>

 <!--By default will be displayed when btn1 is active,this will show when btn1 is clicked and hide when btn2 is clicked -->

  <div class="col-xs-12" id="subid{{index}}" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" >
     <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm filteredDataRow" *ngFor="let subDta of subRegion;let k = index;" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
     <div class=" col-xs-12 rmpm filteredDataName " (click)='loadSubRegionData(index ,kpiName[index],subRegion[k])' style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border-top:1px solid">{{subRegion[k]}}</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <!--this will show when btn2 is clicked and hide when btn1 is clicked -->

    <div class="col-xs-12"  id="proid{{index}}"   style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" *ngIf="pro === index" >
     <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm filteredDataRow"  *ngFor="let subDta of productLine;let k = index;" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" >
     <div class=" col-xs-12 rmpm filteredDataName " (click)='loadSubRegionData()' style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border-top:1px solid">{{productLine[k]}}</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
    kpiName = ['s', 'TO ','d','e'];
  subRegion = ['Ch', 'Ia', 'Ja', 'Ke', 'SE'];
   productLine = ['6A', '7T', '9T', 'UV', 'BA'];
pro: number;
  constructor() {
this.pro= [];
  }
loadSubRegionData(index,kpi,subreg){
  alert(index);
  alert(subreg);
}
showsubid(index,btnid){
  alert(index)
   alert(btnid+index)
}
showproid(index){
   alert(index)
    // alert(id+index)
    this.pro = index;
}
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

There was a small mistake of considering variable pro as a boolean. If you consider it as a number and compare it with the index then it will do what you need.

Comment: The content should toggle when btn1 and btn2 is clicked of the same box.Please, check my plunker.

Comment: Just to get a clarification. btn1 to hide and btn2 to show, correct?

Comment: In your plunker, the toggle is among btn2 of other boxes. The requirement is when in box1, the btn1 is clicked , 'subRegion' should show & ''and 'productLine' should hide; when btn2 is clicked,'productLine' should show and 'subRegion' should hide. Similarly, among box2,box3,box4.

Comment: Have a look at my plunk and see how btn1 and btn2 reacts. The only problem in my plunk is, clicking in one box, changing content of other boxes.

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check now: https://plnkr.co/edit/lXAnIcsOoKpTkivFrzRO?p=preview

Comment: Just to add you need to maintain the click status separately for each set of buttons.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you tell me how to check the id of button which is clicked.?

Comment: You are already passing the button Id as a parameter in both the click events just use that. I have updated the sample with the alert. https://plnkr.co/edit/Xt7lg96IjvRhszTytrVU?p=preview. Do mark as answered as it would help others.

Comment: Please check the id by inspecting, its a dynamic id and it is different from each button.

Comment: I have added the button id alert to the code as you need. You are making the button Ids using a constant string plus the index so you need to do the same in your ts. https://plnkr.co/edit/Xt7lg96IjvRhszTytrVU?p=preview

Comment: loadSubRegionData(index,kpi,subreg){
  alert(index);
  alert(subreg);
  // for index 0,1,2---- onclick of 'ch' show nwDts[0],onclick of 'la' show nwDts[1] at box1,box2 respectively.
}

Comment: I am not able to understand the following `loadSubRegionData(index,kpi,subreg){ alert(index); alert(subreg); // for index 0,1,2---- onclick of 'ch' show nwDts[0],onclick of 'la' show nwDts[1] at box1,box2 respectively. }` The ids are displayed and the buttons are also working as needed.  Can you explain what you want?